# Jawbone EndPoints API returning 141 intermittently

Tags: jawbone

We have integrated our application with the Jawbone API to get user steps. We are able to complete the OAuth2 connection process successfully but we are facing issues while getting the user steps. 
We are using the following Moves Endpoint
https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/moves

The issue is it works intermittently for some of our users and sometimes it returns with 
**Code 141 Function Not Found** Error. 
Could you please help me find out why that error might be coming. As in what situation is that error code returned by your API.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible test case? Is there a particular user or call that always returns a 141? If you need to send a user token, please email it to apisupport@jawbone.com

Comment: Not necessarily. It gets resolved the moment the user reconnects. But then again after 2-3 syncs it happens again.

Comment: As far as I know, the Jawbone servers don't send 141 responses. Are you using a particular framework? When you say syncs, what does your app do?

Comment: By sync I mean our app tries to get the step count using the Jawbone API https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/moves. The response to this request from Jawbone is a 141.

Comment: Could you send the full headers of the request and the full response to apisupport@jawbone.com? I've never seen our servers send a 141 response, so I'll need to try to reproduce with your details.

Comment: Extremely sorry for reporting this issue. The issue was on our server.

Comment: No worries. Glad you found it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not a issue. There was a bug on our server which has been fixed now. Sorry for reporting it.